# Object Orientation - return a value

Tags: python

```
class Duration(object):
    def __init__(self, minutes, seconds):
        self.minutes = minutes
        self.seconds = seconds

    def get_minutes(self):
        return self.minutes
    def get_seconds(self):
        return self.seconds
    def total_seconds(self):  #This part is wrong 
        return 60*(self.get_minutes()) + self.get_seconds()
```

This is my code.

I am suppose to find the total seconds `(Duration(3, 30)).total_seconds)` should give me `210` but now i am getting this `<bound method Duration.total_seconds of <__main__.Duration object at 0x0211AD90>>`
How do I get the `210` ?

Comment: **total_seconds** is a method, which you aren't calling. You are obtaining a ref to it.

Comment: Remove the `get` methods, there is no reason for them since you can already access `seconds` and `minutes` perfectly well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to skip the parentheses, make `total_seconds` a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
@property
def total_seconds(self):
```

Now it does exactly what you want:

```
>>> Duration(3, 30).total_seconds
210
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your, simply, you have to invoke the method instead of fetching it:

```
>>> print((Duration(3, 30)).total_seconds())
210
```

Note the `total_seconds()` not `total_seconds`
When you call it without the `()`, python returns the method instance but does not invoke it.

Comment: This is right. So the original code is correct, it's just the `print` invoking it that's wrong.

Comment: Okay then what if i want (Duration(3, 30)).total_seconds) ?

Comment: @user3398505, That is what it will give. Your call is incorrect. The one I have shown is the correct one. Same result.

Comment: @user3398505: If you want to treat the method as a property then use the `@property` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

This should be

```
print((Duration(3, 30)).total_seconds())
                                     ^^
```

In python, functions are object and can be printed. that is what you are seeing.